# Algebra and guesswork

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d+e=200\\ \\
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=1870
\end{cases}

Please find the value of $e$. I have no idea how to solve these equations. The actual problem is different, but I have narrowed it down to this. Trust me with that.

Comment: To solve a system of equations with 5 variables for an unique solution you need 5 equations/ btw, what have you tried? It's better if you include some of your thoughts

Comment: To get a unique solution, you need more equations.

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d,e$ integers?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Unless, of course, there are no real solutions.

Comment: For positive reals, I can however give you the range of the values $e$ can take. Think about cauchy-schwarz and related inequalities, mon cher!

Comment: @Charlievicky:  why are you specifically interested in the value of $e$ when the equations are basically symmetric in all the variables?

Comment: Unless, of course there are no real solutions : )

Comment: My computer quickfire resulted in no positive integer solutions.

Comment: This question is an old question from the USAMO(1978, 1): It is quite similar to http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/usa/usoln/usol781.html

Answer (score 4):

Actually, these equations have no solution in the real numbers.  Note that the arithmetic mean of the five numbers is $\frac{200}{5} = 40$ while the quadratic mean is $\sqrt{\frac{1870}{5}} = 19.339\ldots$, contradicting the $QM-AM$ inequality.

Comment: positive reals, you mean.

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän No, QM-AM holds in the general real numbers.  (Think about it.)

Comment: Proof: $QM(a,b,c,d,e) = QM(|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|,|e|) \ge AM(|a|,|b|,|c|,|d|,|e|) \ge AM(a,b,c,d,e)$.

Comment: Thanks, inequalities is a bit rusty.